# USB Drive not detected on Antergos after using it on Windows 8.1

Tags: usb, usb-drive, antergos

I used my school Windows PC to copy the content(to the USB) and now when I connect it to my home computer(running Antergos) it is not detectable.

Other pen drives are working fine. My friend, who also had to copy, has a Windows PC and told me that his pen drive is showing as a shortcut(not accessible).

Tried `fdisk -l`, `lsblk` and `lsusb` but the device is not showing.
Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 23a9:ef18  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c07e Logitech, Inc. G402 Gaming Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp.  /*keyboard*/
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Pardon my English.

EDIT: Reply to KyleH: output for command udevadm monitor:

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[6416.233763] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2 (usb)
KERNEL[6416.234592] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [6416.238130] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2 (usb)
UDEV  [6416.240221] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0 (usb)
```

Comment: If you use 'udevadm monitor' and plug in the usb stick, does it show what dev device is created for it?

Comment: Your comment with output isn't showing for me. Does it say /dev/sdX anywhere, X being your drive? If not, then the kernel isn't recognizing it.

Comment: @KyleH sorry, my bad, here is the output: `monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[6416.233763] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2 (usb)
KERNEL[6416.234592] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [6416.238130] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2 (usb)
UDEV  [6416.240221] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0 (usb)`   It is on the question details.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn't see it originally. It is being detected but you will have to write/edit udev rules to match the device when it is plugged in. Then a device file will be created in the dev directory. Udev rules are fairly straightforward rules files that specify if x property equals y. Something like KERNEL=="hdb", NAME="my_spare_disk" Check arch documentation which is great! https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally solved it.
I just had to create a folder `media` in root folder, i.e., `/media`

After it I connected my USB drive and it worked as before.